# whats wrong with my code jquery ajax jason

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to autofill some fields in form on entering id but its not working.

This is my controller function

```
public function payment()
{
    $crud = new RMCL_grocery_CRUD();
    //$crud->set_theme('bootstrap-v4');
    $crud->set_table('wp_rmcl_pub_payment');
    $crud->set_subject("_payment");
    $crud->callback_add_field('payment_type',array($this,'add_field_callback_1'));
    $crud->callback_edit_field('payment_type',array($this,'add_field_callback_1'));
    $crud->set_js('resources/js/sample.js');
    $name=$this->input->post('subscriber_id');
    $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456','armdb');
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from wp_rmcl_pub_subscription where 
    subscriber_id='$name'");
    $response = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $subscription_type= $row['subscription_type'];
        $magazine_type= $row['magazine_type'];
        $response[] = array("subscription_type" => 
        $subscription_type,"magazine_type" => $magazine_type);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->addData('output', $output);
    $this->render('app/crud_view');   
}
```

This is my jquery

```
$('#field-subscriber_id').change(function(){
    var subscriber_id = $('#field-subscriber_id').val();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType:JASON,
        data: {ajax: 1,subscriber_id: subscriber_id},
        success: function(response){
            $('#field-subscription_type').val('' + response.magazine_type);
            $('#field-magazine_type').val('' + response.subscription_type);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to autofill some fields in form on entering id but its not working.

This is my controller function
it doesn't displaying anything.

Comment: `dataType:JASON` isn't a thing.  It should be `dataType: 'json'` JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Comment: I think its not a typo. He used the same in the title also. There is no type as jason. its JSON

Comment: This ajax request is also missing a `url` option ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `dataType` as `JASON`. Replace it with `'json'`.

```
$('#field-subscriber_id').change(function() {
  var subscriber_id = $('#field-subscriber_id').val();
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      ajax: 1,
      subscriber_id: subscriber_id
    }),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#field-subscription_type').val('' + response.magazine_type);
      $('#field-magazine_type').val('' + response.subscription_type);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: stringify the data before sending. `data:JSON.stringify( {
      ajax: 1,
      subscriber_id: subscriber_id
    })`